# How big sites scale up and optimize to massive traffic?

Tags: optimization

How do sites like Facebook and Twitter optimize their sites for massive traffic. Aside from spending big bucks on getting the best servers, what can be optimized in your code to accommodate massive traffic?

I've read about caching your pages to static HTML, but that's impractical for social networking sites where the pages are constantly updated.

Comment: If you get 10000 access per second on an average, even a 1 second caching will save you 9999 script processing.

Comment: You might be interested in this too (I can't find the original post by SO owners): http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/8/5/stack-overflow-architecture.html

Comment: [Here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Scale-at-Facebook) is a video and presentation describing some of the stuff the engineers at facebook did to scale up.

Answer (score 14):

Facebook is a particularly extreme example of load, but in general, high-traffic sites:

1. use a content delivery network (CDN) for distributing static assets (CSS and JavaScript) and media (images, videos, etc.).
2. use in-memory caches like Memcached whenever possible to reduce load on the database.
3. have a load balancer that distributes traffic to a pool of web servers
4. cache generated HTML fragments (e.g. parts of your profile page) and include them when generating a full response

Comment: +1 Couldn't have said it better myself. For a CDN network, I can vouch for Amazon S3 + Cloudfront which I found to work very well for serving static content. For memory cache, check out Redis as well.

Comment: Why is Facebook a bad example?

Comment: Oh, it's not bad; I'm just saying that most websites will never experience load on the level Facebook or Google experience.

Comment: facebook now has 60,000 servers http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/the-facebook-data-center-faq-page-2/

Answer (score 1):

### Content Delivery Network

Facebook uses static content delivery network for serving photos and videos. Check the source of any image in facebook and you will see something like fbcdn.net.

Comment: Can you atleast explain **what** is CDN, in context of Facebook? For instance, like the link http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=2406207130

Comment: @Kanini You can check-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: What's the difference between Cloud Computing and CDN?